# Docker-stack - get image always from the hub.docker.com

Tags: docker-compose

**Summary**: When I perform a 'docker stack deploy' in an AWS / EC2 environment the local (old) image is used. How can I overrule this behaviour to have the 'docker stack' use the new image from the hub.docker.com? As a workaround I first do a 'docker pull' of the image from index.docker.com before executing the 'docker stack deploy'. Is this extra step needed?

**Situation**:
On a Jenkins server (not on AWS / EC2) I have the following building steps:

- Maven build
- docker login -u ${env.DOCKER_USERNAME} -p ${env.DOCKER_PASSWORD}
- docker build -t local-username/image-name:latest
- docker tag local-username/image-name dockerhub-username/image-name:latest
- docker push dockerhub-username/image-name:latest

The next steps in my Jenkinsfile are executed via a secure shell (ssh) on my AWS environement:

- docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stackname

When I execute this Jenkins job, the docker image is taken from the local image repo on AWS. I want to use the newest image put on hub.docker.com.

When I insert the following action BEFORE the 'docker stack deploy' everything works smoothly:

- docker pull index.docker.io/dockerhub-username/image-name:latest

My questions:

- Why do I need this extra 'docker pull' action?
- How can I remove this action? Just by adding 'index.docker.io' in front of the image in the docker-compose.yml file? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I recommend you to not use the `latest` tag, as that may include breaking changing in the future. I also recommend in each deployment process to target a specific version of an image. If the image tag changes, and it does not exist locally, it will be pulled. Treat images as something that *should* be immutable and that are not intended to be pulled again. This will avoid headaches down the line. (You can force pull in certain scenarios, yet it's still a flakey process.)

Comment: Thank you. Should I change the 'docker-compose.yml' file for each new version of the app? This new 'docker-compose.yml' file contains the 'right' tag of the image. 
What if there is a bug in a docker image, what tag is ideal?

Comment: Why not use `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --resolve-image always`?

Comment: Please elaborate. Maybe it is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra docker pull should, of course not be needed.

What will help you?

- The answer of @Tarun may work.
- Or just name the Docker hub registry. Use the following line in your docker-compose.yml (stack) file

> ```
> servicename:
>   image: index.docker.io/dockerhub-username/image-name
> ```

That will help you.

Maybe this is due to the fact that you build locally or on a separate Jenkins server, push the image to Docker hub and start on a remote shell on EC2. On that EC2 there is only a current image.

I tried the above solution for you, and it worked.

You can just execute the 'docker stack deploy' and the right image is used.